# Switch case: how to do case insensitive string check in matlab

Tags: matlab, switch-statement, case-sensitive

I am using a switch statement like this

```
input('Enter string:') % For example 'VALUE'
switch string
     case {'Value','VALue'.....}
```

for all combinations of upper and lower case.

How can I more efficiently write case insensitive tests in a switch expression?

Answer (score 3):

You could transform both values to lower case using `lower()` and then compare it, like for example:

```
txt = 'Hello, World.';
newTxt = lower(txt);  % newTxt = 'hello, world.'

case {'hello, world.'}
```

You can learn more about it in the official documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`strcmpi`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html)** for  case insensitive comparisons in MATLAB, but you'd want to use `if` statements instead of switches...

```
% If you must use the 's' flag for input, it is directly stored as a string
% so you don't have to input the quotation marks!
str = input('Enter string', 's'); 

if strcmpi(str, 'VALUE')
    % true for 'VAlue', 'VALUe', 'valUE', ...
elseif strcmpi(str, 'anothervalue')
    % true for 'AnotherValue', 'ANOTHERvalue', ...
else
    % Anything else
end
```

---

You can actually use `strcmpi` on a cell array, so you don't need the `if` statements at all (depending on your use).

```
% Define your test strings
mystrings = {'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'};
% Set text (could do via input)
str = 'def';
% Compare ALL 
choice = strcmpi(str, mystrings);
>> choice = [0 1 0 0] % logical vector output
```

So if you structure your code to have the relevant operations within matrices or cells then you can use this `choice` output as a selector, and speed up / streamline your code by not doing any case testing.